# BeautifulSoup can't parse nested div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**EDIT: I managed to solve the problem by changing the parser from html.parser to lxml.**

I'm trying to parse a website and it seems they have unusual number of nested divs.

What I want is every h1 under `div class="agenda-item"`. BUT, I want only the divs under the div with `id = nu-binnenkort` (the other one is `id = archief`, which I am not interested)

I managed to parse every h1, but I don't want the ones under archief. I tried the following code, but it only returns the first h1, for some reason I don't know.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from datetime import datetime

site= "https://www.tac.nu/en/programma/"
req = Request(site)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

programma = soup.find('div',id='nu-binnenkort')
hl1 = programma.find('div',class_='vc_tta-panel-body')
hl2 = hl1.find('div',class_='wpb_text_column')
hl3 = hl2.find('div',class_='wpb_wrapper')
hl4 = hl3.find_all('div',class_='agenda-item')
for div in hl4:
   print(div.h1.text)
```

Any suggestions? Is there a way to parse h1's that has a parent (grand-grand-grand.... in this case) with a specific ID (id=nu-binnenkort in this case)?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want h1's under div class="agenda-item" (texts of h1's)